# XSL copy-of copies outer node

Tags: xslt, mathml

I'm trying to process the following XML snippet:

```
        <inlineequation><mml:math>
            <!-- eqn: [-1,1]:-->
            <mml:mfenced open="[" close="]">
                <mml:mn>-1</mml:mn>
                <mml:mn>1</mml:mn>
            </mml:mfenced>
        </mml:math></inlineequation>
```

The best result I got is to copy the entire markup, by using the *copy-of* function:

```
<xsl:template match="para/inlineequation">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, the transformed XML will have also the *inlineequation* node, while I want to strip it out. Indeed the correct output shall be:

```
        <mml:math><mml:mfenced open="[" close="]">
            <mml:mn>-1</mml:mn>
            <mml:mn>1</mml:mn>
        </mml:mfenced></mml:math>
```

How to achieve the result above? The result I'm getting now is:

```
        <inlineequation><mml:math>
        <mml:mfenced open="[" close="]">
            <mml:mn>-1</mml:mn>
            <mml:mn>1</mml:mn>
        </mml:mfenced>
        </mml:math></inlineequation>
```

Comment: This is not hard to achieve, but can you confirm you want the mml:math node stripped out too, as it is also not present in your output XML. Thanks!

Comment: Ops... It shall not stripped out (I think). The problem is that the transformed XML is inlined into C# source code, processed by Doxygen: I have not yet experimented on the necessary markup to display equations correctly. I suppose mml:math tag shall be included as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
<xsl:template match="para/inlineequation">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or, if you have correctly declared the namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="para/inlineequation">
    <xsl:copy-of select="mml:math"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="mml:math">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```